# How to add new users from a logged-in user?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-2.2, asp.net-core-identity

I have this weird behaviour when it comes to creating a new users from scratch(registration) and creating new ones from a logged in user that doesn't depend on the DB underneath(in this case I'm using postgreSQL).
But first here's the relationship:
[image: Tables relationships]

Now both at registration time and logged-in time I do use `UserManager` for the creation of the users.

First I create a new `UserSetting`, `SaveChanges()` and follow by assigning to the `AppUser` property `UserSettingId` the value of the `Id` of the new created entity.

Here's where it fails depending if you are already a registered and logged-in user or you are a new registering user, the code doesn't change:

```
var userSettings = await _userService.UserSettings.AddAsync(new UserSettings
{
    LanguageId = langId,
    ThemeId = themeId
});
//wrapper to the Context.SaveChangesAsync()
//failure point!
if (!await _userService.SaveChangesAsync<bool>())
```

And the exception error(at the creation of a new user from an already logged-in user) talks about a `PK_LanguageId` already existing as if I was creating a new Language entity but, as you can see, I'm just assigning just a default `langId` to the new `UserSetting`. Here's the exception screenshot:

[image]

(sorry for the italian, it does auto-translate)
Short translation: duplicated key for `Languages`, as if it was trying to insert also a new `Language` entity.

And at the `Startup` the registered service(`_userService`) is transient.

And here's the model classes and their configuration in `OnModelCreating`:

```
public class AppUser : IdentityUser
{
    public long UserSettingsId { get; set; }
    public virtual UserSettings UserSettings { get; set; }
    //...other properties
}
public class UserSettings
{
    public long Id { get; set; }

    public int LanguageId { get; set; }
    public virtual Language Language { get; set; }

    public int ThemeId { get; set; }
    public virtual Theme Theme { get; set; }

    public virtual AppUser AppUser { get; set; }
}
public class Theme
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [StringLength(10)]
    public string Type { get; set; }
}
public class Language
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(2)]
    public string Code { get; set; }
}


builder.Entity<AppUser>().HasKey(u => u.Id);
builder.Entity<AppUser>().HasOne(u => u.UserSettings).WithOne(us => us.AppUser);

builder.Entity<UserSettings>().HasKey(us => us.Id);
builder.Entity<UserSettings>().Property(us => us.Id).ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
builder.Entity<UserSettings>().HasOne(us => us.Language);
builder.Entity<UserSettings>().HasOne(us => us.Theme);
```

What I'm doing wrong? Why it does behave so differently? Is there a different way to create users from an already logged-in user?

Comment: Could you please share your model classes as well?

Comment: Can you please provide the exception.

Comment: @Zze Provided the exception screenshot.

Comment: So far I don't see anything wrong in the code you provided. The only idea I have is that the language might be mistakenly added to the DBContext somewhere in a different place. When you call `SaveChangesAsync`, you save all the changes that have been done to the context anywhere, so might be that.

Comment: @Sergey checked again and there's no such place, nowhere I add a language

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the source of the behaviour, it's the damn `UserManager.GetUserAsync()`, which I user to get the currently logged-in user with added `UserSettings` later on to propagate the "Admin"'s settings to the new creating account.

`GetUserAsync(User)` does return an entity that does keep being tracked(instead of, as I thought, being like `AsNoTracking()`). So consequently when I did fill it's `UserSetting` I did in fact added a new `UserSetting` with new sub classes properties!

Sooo, never expect `UserManager` give you the user without tracking!

Thanks for everyone involved with the effort.

Comment: Glad that you found it! Maybe this post will help someone in the future.

Answer (score 2):

The problem might be that you are adding object to the database context which marks it as added. Because database context isn't aware of existence `Language` and `Theme` objects it is trying to insert all of them.

It may be issue with postgreSQL provider. You might want to check opened issues.

I'd suggest to try loading `Language` object from database first and then try to add new `UserSettings`.

Comment: I tried to provide directly the virtual properties `Language` and `Theme`, without `AsNoTracking()` and something changed, now the exception is about the _new_ `UserSettings` having the same settings `Id` as the currently logged-in user! Just WTF is going on...

Comment: Can you share OnModelCreating method? or maybe whole DbContext to take a look at this. Thanks